# Question on Pandas -> Exception Ignored: Unhashable Type: 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, exception, typeerror

I created a pandas DataFrame by grouping by two values and received a table similar to the one below:

| First Name | Column A |
| --- | --- |
| Samuel | [1,2,3] |
| Joshua | [4,5,6] |
| Richard | [7,8,9] |
| Michael | [7,8,9] |
| Henry | [7,8,9] |

Next, I grouped by Column A to figure out how many unique first names each list of numbers had, and received the error below:

> ```
> Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._call_map_locations'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4588, in > pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
> ```

I was confused when I was returned a pandas Series with the index being of type numpy array. Why was the exception ignored in this case?

Comment: convert the `column A` to `string`. Consider it as a string rather than list. This is one of the hack

Comment: or make them as tuple. then you can group

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: The error implies that it tried to use a dict or other hashed mapping to create the groups.  But `numpy` arrays cannot be used as `dict` keys. It appears to have caught the error, displayed it, and then moved on to some alternative method of grouping.

Answer (score 0):

try converting the list to tuple by `df['Column A'].map(tuple)` or `df['Column A'].map(str)`

```
df.groupby(df['Column A'].map(tuple))['First Name'].unique()
```

---

```
Column A
(1, 2, 3)                     [Samuel]
(4, 5, 6)                     [Joshua]
(7, 8, 9)    [Richard, Michael, Henry]
Name: First Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. Casting as a string or tuple will remove the error message, but my question is about why the exception is ignored and the table is created. The index is the numpy array and the Series is still created and I wasn't sure why it was still created.